# C++ Help, Password Verifier

Tags: c++, visual-c++

sorry if I sound like an idiot or my code itself is bad, but i need all the help i could get. A lot of people have written this code but I did not want to look at theirs and basically copy and paste. So here's the problem, when i try running this program, it gives me that identifier _TCHAR is undefined, and gives me a warning on line 20 that " < signed/unsigned mismatch". again I'd love any help I can get.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{
    const int size = 1000;

    char password[size];

    int count;

    int times1 = 0;

    int times2 = 0;

    int times3 = 0;
    cout << "Please enter your password: ";
    cin.getline(password, size);


    if (strlen(password) < 6){

        cout << "Not valid, your password should be atleast 6 letters";

    }

    for (count = 0; count < strlen(password); count++)
    {

        if (isupper(password[count])) {

            times1++;

        }

        if (islower(password[count])){

            times2++;

        }

        if (isdigit(password[count])){

            times3++;

        }

    }

    if (times1 == 0) {

        cout << "Invalid, the password should contain atleast one uppercase letter";

    }

    if (times2 == 0) {

        cout << "Invalid, the password should contain atleast one lowercase letter";

    }

    if (times3 == 0) {

        cout << "Invalid, the password should contain atleast one digit";

    }



    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `_TCHAR` is a Microsoft invention.  It is not a standard C++ type.

Comment: `_TCHAR` should be in `windows.h`. Try including that file.

Comment: TChar is one of Windows' many character types. It's not defined as part of standard C++, so you're going to have to include the proper file--in this case, [I believe it's TCHAR.h](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc). the signed/unsigned warning is telling you that you're comparing an unsigned type (can't be negative) with a signed type (can be negative). Unexpected things tend to happen in those circumstances, hence the warning.

Comment: You're not using either argument to `main` anyway, so why not rip them both out. `int main()` is conforming. And you forgot to `#include <cctype>`, the keeper of your `isxxxx` declarations.

Comment: Including a windows header is overkill.  Just use the standard signature for the `main` function `int main( )`.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply @PaulMckenzie , how would I fix that? My friend told me to use that, even though I do not believe he is very good with this, lol

Comment: @MARTY Stop listening to your friend.  Any good C++ book shows how to declare `main` properly.

Comment: I believe `TCHAR`  comes with windows.h and  `_TCHAR` requires `tchar.h` .  And yes, it's [non standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for handling compilation with/without unicode.

Comment: Thank you all, I truly appreciated all the help, I was able to get past that stinking TCHAR. Now i just need some sort of loop to make sure that i go back to the question when i enter the wrong answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap everything in a while loop (from times1=0, times2=0, times3=0 to just before cin.get()). Use a bool variable called something like validPass and initialize to true. When one of the requirements fails just make validPass=false. The while should be while(validPass==false){...}

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


int main()

{
    const int size = 1000;

    char password[size];

    int count;

    bool validPass;
    do
    {
        validPass = true;
        int times1 = 0;

        int times2 = 0;

        int times3 = 0;
        cout << "Please enter your password: ";
        cin.getline(password, size);


        if (strlen(password) < 6){

            cout << "Not valid, your password should be atleast 6 letters";
            validPass = false;
            continue;

        }

        for (count = 0; count < strlen(password); count++)
        {

            if (isupper(password[count])) {

                times1++;

            }

            if (islower(password[count])){

                times2++;

            }

            if (isdigit(password[count])){

                times3++;

            }

        }

        if (times1 == 0) {

            cout << "Invalid, the password should contain atleast one uppercase letter";
            validPass = false;
            continue;

        }

        if (times2 == 0) {

            cout << "Invalid, the password should contain atleast one lowercase letter";
            validPass = false;
            continue;

        }

        if (times3 == 0) {

            cout << "Invalid, the password should contain atleast one digit";
            validPass = false;
            continue;

        }

    } while (!validPass);

        cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are amazing, thank you so much for all the help, I can finally rest in peace. this was my final extra credit program, now i hope the professor likes it and gives me a 102% in the class